# Hide a Facebook application's "Add to My page" option

Tags: facebook, tabs, addition

I'm currently developing an app for facebook.
It will be used for fan-gating users to a specific page.
However, whenever I visit my app's profile page, it shows an option "Add to My page".

I'd like my app to be exclusively availible to the page I'm developing it for, and disable the option for everybody else, to add the app. Is this possible in any way?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible, but you can use the 'page' parameter in the `signed_request` sent to your app to determine which page the request is coming from, and not return any content for the 'wrong' page